# How would I get options from object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

This is the structure:

```
e {options: {…}, _latlng: M, _radius: 10, _initHooksCalled: true}
options:
id: "https://example.com/travel/weekend-a-barcelona/"
__proto__: Object
__parent: e {options: {…}, _latlng: M, _group: e, _zoom: 6, _markers: Array(2), …}
_events: {click: Array(1), dragstart: Array(1), move: Array(1), dragend: Array(1)}
_initHooksCalled: true
_latlng: M {lat: 41.39483307195536, lng: 2.148767850000013}
_leaflet_id: 495
_radius: 10
__proto__: e
```

I need to get the link `id: "https://example.com/travel/weekend-a-barcelona/"`

I tried

```
 circle.on('click', function (e) {
   var circleLink = e.target.options();
   alert(circleLink);
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: e.target.options is not a function`

Comment: `var circleLink = e.target.options` options is an object, not a function

Comment: @SergioEscudero how would I get its value then?

Comment: `e.target.options.id`, with no `()` anywhere.

Comment: @IvanSanchez oh right, isee

Comment: @rob.m correct just its value

Comment: @IvanSanchez place that into an answer with a bit of explanation and i'll accept it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access nested objects like below. Basically you're getting the value of options using `e.options`, and then to get the link, you have to get the value of options (which we previously found out was `e.options`) and add `.id` to the end. You end up with `e.options.id`

```js
const e = { options: { id: "https://example.com/travel/weekend-a-barcelona/" } };

console.log(e.options.id);
```